# List NTP information of gcloud kubernetes

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

Is there an option to show, that `metadata.google.internal` is used as NTP when i connect to a pod or to the kubernetes VM?
I tried the following: `ntpq -p`, which results in command not found, but was listed on https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instances. This file does not exist: vim `/etc/ntp.conf`. I need that as a proof, showing which server is used.

Comment: Are you using `Container-Optimized OS` in your GKE cluster?

Comment: One workaround would be to go for pod with package manager, install nslookup on it and check `$ nslookup metadata.google.internal`. It should give the IP address of `169.254.169.254`. After that you can check `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service` and specifically the part of `Synchronized to time server`.

Answer (score 4):

When you create a GKE cluster you have an option to specify which operating system  will be the base for your Kubernetes installation. You have the options to choose from:

- Container-Optimized OS (cos)
- Container-Optimized OS (cos) with containerd
- Ubuntu
- Ubuntu with containerd

You can choose it by following a path in Google Cloud Platform:

*Kubernetes Engine* -> *Create a Kubernetes cluster* -> *Node-pools* -> *default-pool* -> *Nodes* -> ***Image type***.

What you choose will affect what tools you will be able to use internally on the nodes.

---

### Container-Optimized OS

A word about Container-Optimized OS:

> Container-Optimized OS is an operating system image for your [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute) VMs that is optimized for running Docker containers. With Container-Optimized OS, you can bring up your Docker containers on Google Cloud Platform quickly, efficiently, and securely. Container-Optimized OS is maintained by Google and is based on the open source [Chromium OS](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os) project.
>
> --  *[Cloud.google.com: Container-optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs)*

Please take a look on official documentation talking about features, benefits and limitations of Container-Optimized OS: [Cloud.google.com: Container-optimized OS features,benefits and limitations](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/features-and-benefits)

> Container-Optimized OS does not include a package manager; as such, you'll be unable to install software packages directly on an instance. However, you can use [CoreOS toolbox](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/toolbox) to install and run debugging and admin tools in an isolated container.

**As said in above documentation there is no package manager available but you can use CoreOS toolbox to debug and install required software.**

You can check which server is used by your Container-Optimized OS node with systemd as follows:

`$ systemctl status systemd-timesyncd`

It should give you an output similar to this:

```sh
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-03-03 21:17:35 UTC; 6 days ago
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
 Main PID: 219 (systemd-timesyn)
   Status: "Synchronized to time server 169.254.169.254:123 (169.254.169.254)."
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 832.0K
      CPU: 591ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-timesyncd.service
           └─219 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
```

Please take a specific look on

```sh
   Status: "Synchronized to time server 169.254.169.254:123 (169.254.169.254)."
```

Above message indicates which server is used by node to synchronize time.

You can get more information about IP address of `169.254.169.254` by following: [Serverfault.com: What is this IP address 169.254.169.254](https://serverfault.com/questions/427018/what-is-this-ip-address-169-254-169-254/427022)

You can check the DNS name of `169.254.169.254` with mentioned CoreOS Toolbox on your node and `nslookup`:

- `$ /usr/bin/toolbox`
- `$ apt-get install -y dnsutils`
- `$ nslookup 169.254.169.254`

It should give you an output:

```sh
Server:         169.254.169.254
Address:        169.254.169.254#53

Non-authoritative answer:
254.169.254.169.in-addr.arpa    name = metadata.google.internal.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

Above output indicates that the address of `169.254.169.254` is the mentioned `metadata.google.internal`

---

### Ubuntu

With GKE cluster created with Ubuntu image you check NTP information with:

- systemd
- dhcp lease
- `ntptrace`
- `nslookup`

#### Systemd

You can check which NTP server is used by your Ubuntu node the same as with Container-Optimized OS as follows:

`$ systemctl status systemd-timesyncd`

#### DHCP lease

The DHCP lease contains information about NTP server. You can get information about DHCP lease as follows:

`USER@NODE:~$ cat /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases`

Output of above command should look like below:

```sh
lease {
  interface "eth0";
  fixed-address 10.156.0.X;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.255;
  option routers 10.156.0.1;
  option dhcp-lease-time 86400;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option domain-name-servers 169.254.169.254;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 169.254.169.254;
  option interface-mtu 1460;
  option domain-search "X.internal.", "Y.internal";
  option ntp-servers 169.254.169.254;
  option rfc3442-classless-static-routes 32,10,156,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,10,156,0,1;
  option host-name "X.internal";
  option domain-name "X.internal";
  renew 2 2020/03/10 09:12:37;
  rebind 2 2020/03/10 18:40:09;
  expire 2 2020/03/10 21:40:09;
}
```

Please take a specific look on:

```sh
  option ntp-servers 169.254.169.254;
```

This line indicates the NTP server used.

#### Ntptrace

`Ntptrace` should show `169.254.169.254` as follows:

```sh
localhost: stratum 3, offset 0.000058, synch distance 0.026242
169.254.169.254: timed out, nothing received
***Request timed out
```

#### Nslookup

You can check the `ntp-server` with  `nslookup` in the same manner as in CoreOS Toolbox if it matches the `metadata.google.internal`.

Please let me know if you have any questions in this topic.

Answer (score 0):

**2024 Updated answer to reflect changes:**

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/configure-ntp
^-- points out that linux VMs use either ntpd or chronyd

- try to ssh into a GKE node
- tip: you can follow these directions https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding, to add a VPC firewall rule that will allow SSH from GCP's IAP (Identity Aware Proxy), which will allow the ssh via browser and ssh using gcloud command's to automagically work.

From there try the following:

```bash
systemctl list-units | grep ntp
systemctl list-units | grep time
systemctl list-units | grep chrony
# chronyd.service         loaded active running   NTP client/server
# ^-- ok proof chronyd is installed and maintaining NTP

systemctl status chronyd
# ^-- works but not much of interest

chronyc sources
# MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
# ===============================================================================
# ^* metadata.google.internal      2   8   377   187  -3733ns[-4873ns] +/-  315us
```

^-- chronyc sources (which I learned about the existance of from GCP's docs)
shows the default NTP server is being used (metadata.google.internal)