# Why my local DNS is not used?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos8

I just installed `bind` on CentOS 8 using: linuxapt.com/blog/caching-dns-server-on-centos-8 and nslookup google.com` shows:

```
Server:         169.254.169.254
Address:        169.254.169.254#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.15.78
Name:   google.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:4004:810::200e
```

bind config:

```
listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; any; };
allow-query { localhost; any; };
allow-query-cache { localhost; any; };
recursion yes;
```

169.254.169.254 is not my IP. Am I missing something?

**EDIT** there is this in my /etc/hosts `169.254.169.254 metadata.google.internal  # Added by Google` - i dont understand how does it affect dns

resolve config:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search us-east4-c.c.haawks.internal c.haawks.internal google.internal
nameserver 169.254.169.254
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this IP address: 169.254.169.254?](https://serverfault.com/questions/427018/what-is-this-ip-address-169-254-169-254)

Comment: nope. i dont care what it is. my question is - why it is NOT my IP since I just installed dns locally

Comment: please share your /etc/resolv.conf. your OS doesn't have to use your local dns server unless you tell your OS to use the local DNS server.

Comment: see my "answer" - some serious magic is in place! :)

Comment: I just saw your answer. what's wrong with this output? you are using the internal dns of gcp. it resolves the domain through upper/root dns server (recursion). what do you want to see? do you want to see your local server's ip when you query  `nslookup google.com` ?

and please share your /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: yes i want to use my local DNS not google one. i expect it to cache requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, NetorkManager is running and it will write `/etc/resolv.conf` with the settings received via DHCP.

As you run a local DNS server, you don't want that, and you basically want to always use 127.0.0.1 as nameserver. You need to tell NetworkManager that you want that:

add `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/90-dns-none.conf` with

```
[main]
dns=none
```

And issue `systemctl reload NetworkManager`. See also `man NetworkManager.conf`.

Afterwards edit `/etc/resolv.conf` to your liking.

---

Btw, you could have also marked the file as readonly with `chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf` followed by `systemctl reload NetworkManager`. Similar result.

Or, you could replace `/etc/resolv.conf` with a symlink to the actual file with `nameserver 127.0.0.1`, followed by `systemctl reload NetworkManager`. That also tells NetworkManager to stay away.

Comment: yes that what i did - symlink

Answer (score 1):

apparently (on GCP machines) command `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` overrides `/etc/resolv.conf` every time and my nameserver is lost.. not sure why but its a different question.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-resolved

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your local DNS can resolve the domains. You can test your local DNS server through the `dig` command:

```
dig google.com @127.0.0.1
```

If it works then, open this file: `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eXX`

and add your local DNS server to this file:

```
DNS1=127.0.0.1
```

Then restart your NetworkManager. It is going to update your /etc/resolv.conf file.

Comment: Didnt work. the resolve config is overriden again

Answer (score 0):

On Centos7 to persist /etc/resolve.conf on reboot
add
#prevents DHCP from overwriting the /etc/resolv.conf file

PEERDNS=no

to
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-adapter_name_file

Source :Linux Bible by Negus

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/525619)